# Why doesn't the boolean modifier work for me?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image]

I want to use the top half of the circle to make a cut but whenever I apply the boolean modifier, the circle just stays there and becomes attached to my other object.

I've managed to make the cut in a standard cube but not sure why it's not working for this...?

Answer (score 15):

That's because of the limitation of approach of how inner/outer surface are calculated in Boolean modifier. Current Boolean uses Carve library. Carve will perform boolean operation only if the intersection of two meshes is a closed loop of edges.

As shown in your image, the object is not a closed manifold one, which confuses the edge classifier. This is listed in [Boolean modifier limitation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Boolean_Modifier).

To solve this, I suggest adding a **Solidify** modifier on top of **Boolean** modifier, with a very small Thickness Value (such as `0.00001`). After applying both modifiers, you can press <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles** to clean the mesh, and select all faces, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to correct normals. (This sounds like a trick, but it works in this case, since there's nothing you can do with the current Boolean approach, which got its own advantages as well as limitations)

[image]

**[Example file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27256)**

By the way, in the coming **[2.70](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.70/)**, Boolean modifier supports ngons, which means you can generate much better and cleaner results (as shown in above image). You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

There might be a problem with the normals. Select the Cylinder and go into edit mode, and recalculate the normals, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>. Do the same for the box object.

1. Select the Box like object (not the cylinder).
2. Add a boolean modifier
3. Select the cylinder as the Object in the Boolean Modifier settings
4. You need to set the boolean modifier to difference.

[image]

---

If you have other modifier on the mesh you might need to apply those first, before you apply the boolean modifier.

Comment: I have but it still doesn't work...

Comment: @user2302835, updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the triangulate modifier on both shapes.

I also had the problems with larger models that are may of not perfect quality. 
I also made some afford in building the model with quads or remiss all didn't work.

In these cases put a triangulate modifier on both shapes and place the boolean modifier afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Boolean Prep - Subdivide]

I think I've gotten around that by selecting just the faces which are going to be cut and subdividing them a few times prior.

I'm suspecting that the additional geometry helps give the Boolean operator more to work with.

[image: Boolean Anomaly]
I did get a slight anomaly on the inside of the wheel well but looks easy to fix if I feel like it and it'll be hidden by the tire anyhow.

Overall I'm finding that additional geometry helps with a lot of things in Blender and I'm slowly getting better at targeting where and how I place that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a mesh that instead of doing a union It just combined the two meshed like in a join.
[image: Correctly united mesh.]
[image: Badly united mesh]
I used the overlap threshold to change how much the mesh is cut into.The overlap threshold is in the Boolean modifier.
[image: Boolean modifier with overlap threshold]

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue. I generated the cylinder by extrusion of a circle. My problem was that the circle was originally placed exactly on the face of the other object. To solve this, I just moved the cylinder a bit in the normal direction to prevent the edges of the original circle to be at the intersection.