# Boolean Modifier fails or makes object disappear

Tags: modifiers

I cant seem to Cut a hole in Any objects with the Difference operation while using the Boolean Modifier, All it does make Objects Disappear or Instead give me an Error(Unable to perform Boolean Operation)

[image]

Comment: May you please upload a .blend file? the only time I had this problem was when I selected an object with no mash overlapping but I can't tell that from you screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: Possible related issue with this question: [Why doesn't the boolean modifier work for me?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7494/696)

Comment: It could be that you are trying to affect a mesh that is ***non-manifold*** read:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

Comment: My build of Blender 2.73 performs the Boolean operations flawlessly, either it is a bug or you are trying to perform the operation on a non-,manifold mesh as Cegaton mentioned. We need your .blend file to be sure. One thing you can try is adding a new cube scaled by 2, and adding a new cylinder and scaling on the z axis by 3, and performing the operation with them.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your mesh with the *Boolean* modifier is a 2-dimensional plane, this will cause some issues with your Boolean operations. I noticed some very unusual behavior when trying to perform a Boolean operation on a 2-dimensional mesh (*final result, difference mesh  has been deleted*):

[image: Boolean Difference 2D]

However if I extruded the plane a small amount, the result was completely normal:

[image: Boolean Difference 3D]

I think you will have to add some thickness to your mesh before using the *Boolean* modifier if you want to achieve expected results.

Also see [**this answer**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/why-doesnt-the-boolean-modifier-work-for-me/7494#7494) to a very similar question.